# Why d3 bar chard cannot show in the browser in the example?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vue.js

I would like to make a d3 bar chart. But there is nothing shown in the browser and I got an error message'Error id mounted hook:"TypeError: Cannot read prototype '0'of undefined"'

I cannot seem to be able to solve. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my coding?

Thank you very much!

I have tried below

```
<template>
 <div>
  <div id='chart'></div>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
 import * as d3 from 'd3'

 export default {
   name: 'priceChart',
   data() {
   return {
     price_open: 0,
     price_min: 1,
     price_max: 2,
     price_close: 3,
     w: 500,
     h: 400,
     paddingLeft: 30,
     paddingRight: 30,
     paddingTop: 20,
     paddingBottom: 20,
     volumeData:[10,20,30,40,33,24,12,5]

    }
  },

 methods: {

    createSvg() {
      const svg = d3.select('#chart')
       .append('svg')
       .attr('width', this.w)
       .attr('height', this.h);
      let xScale = d3.scaleBand()
       .domain(d3.range(this.volumeData.length))
       .rangeRound([0, this.w - this.paddingLeft - this.paddingRight]);

      let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
       .domain([0, d3.max(this.volumeData)])
       .range([this.h - this.paddingTop - this.paddingBottom, 0])

      let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
      let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

      let rectPadding = 4;
      let rects = svg.selectAll('.MyRect')
        .data(this.volumeData)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'MyRect')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.paddingLeft + ',' + 
      this.paddingTop + ')')
        .attr('x', (d, i) => (xScale(i) + rectPadding) / 2)
        .attr('y', (d, i) => yScale(d))
        .attr('width',xScale.rangeRound()-this.rectPadding)
        .attr('height',d=>this.height-this.paddingTop- 
      this.paddingBottom-yScale(d))
        .attr('fill','red')
       }
      },
    mounted() {
      this.createSvg();
     }
    }
```

Comment: `xScale` is a function. `xScale.rangeRound()` is undefined

Comment: I created a codepen for this https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/PeVqWZ

Comment: I see! Thanks for your help!@ittus

Comment: @Sylvia You can use `xScale.bandwidth()` to get the `width` of each datapoint in band scales